# How to create Raster statistics with GDAL externally?

Tags: python, gdal, statistics, gdalinfo

If I want to create a GDAL PAM statistics file with the command `gdalinfo -stats` from a GRIB file, e.g. needed for [DynamicColorMapping](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/colormap/index.html#), GDAL only creates the statistics internally inside the sourcefile. Is it possible to force `gdalinfo -stats` to create the additional file (.aux.xml)?

A way to do this is programmatically with Python and to tinker with the XML, but that doesn't fit my needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a workaround you can use command

```
gdalinfo -stats -hist input.tif
```

Selecting the histogram option triggers the creation of input.tif.aux.xml file.

**EDIT**

I have learned that actually there is no need to use the -hist workaround. There is a GDAL configuration option GDAL_PAM_ENABLED that forces the creation of the .aux.xml file. Usage example:

```
gdalinfo test.tif -stats --config GDAL_PAM_ENABLED TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

The following isn't a direct GDAL solution for your question, but it might help. The Orfeo Toolbox command [`otbcli_ComputeImagesStatistics`](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org//Applications/ComputeImagesStatistics.html) can be used to generate raster band statistics and output them to an XML file. For instance:

```
otbcli_ComputeImagesStatistics -il input_image.tif -out output.xml
```